# How do I sort a 2D array using a Listbox which displays the first row of the array?

Tags: arrays, vba, listbox

- I'm working in VBA (not in the excel IDE but I have its object library as a
  reference) and I have a userform with a listbox which displays all
  the worksheets within an excel workbook.
- when one of these listbox items(worksheets) is selected, a specific
  range of    cells within the selected worksheet is put into a 2D
  array and the items from the top row (column headers) in each column
  are then used to populate a 2nd listbox.
- I have 2 command buttons which allow me to move the individual items
  up or down within the 2nd listbox(depending on if the item can move
  up or down from its position in the listbox).
- What I am trying to achieve now is, after I have reordered the items
  in the 2nd listbox, I want the 2D array to be sorted to match the
  arrangement of the listbox items so that when I loop through the
  array I can manipulate its data in this specific order.

I'm not sure precisely how I go about it, my first thought would be loop through the items in the listbox starting at 0, use string comparison of selected item against each value in the top row of the array, if a match is found, move that entire column into a new array, repeat until at the end of all listbox items.

I'm entirely sure that's the best way to approach it so I'm looking for thoughts on how best to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply copy the list's items into a fresh new array and work with it?

Comment: The list only displays the first row of the array so moving that to a new array will not copy over the remaining rows in the array (unless I am missing something?)